# Highlighting with Pygmentize in Phabricator not working

Tags: pygments, phabricator

I installed Phabricator for working with Python projects. Everything is ok, but files view present them, as plain text.  I want to some highlighting provided by Pygmentize utility.

I have installed Pygments

```
sudo pip install Pygments
```

Checked from all users, **pygmentize** script is available, and located at /usr/local/bin.
I changed

```
'pygments.enabled' => true,
```

settings in myconfig.conf.php file of phabricator.
But it's not working ?! I can't find any log crashes, or something else. Have you any ideas why it can happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I received answer from Github-Issues service. The reason was that httpd user can't call this function, here is sample which extends own $PATH enviroment. I added this to myconfig.conf.php file:

```
'environment.append-paths' => array('/usr/local/bin'),
```

It is strongly recommended to add path with pygmentize to your path.

Comment: where do you get the myconfig.conf.php. I've never seen there is a config for

Answer (score 0):

config file located at:

`phabricator/conf/local/local.json`

I have add in my config

```
"environment.append-paths": ["\/bin","\/usr\/bin","\/usr\/local\/bin","\/usr\/local\/sbin","\/usr\/local\/bin","\/opt\/local\/sbin","\/opt\/local\/bin","\/usr\/sbin","\/usr\/bin","\/sbin"],
```

I am using SmartOS ($PATH locates in /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin)